Editing Markdown Document from R with Embedded Outputs in Github
I have followed the following instructions and successfully published my R markdown document to my Github web page with embedded graphics/outputs. Now, if I need to edit the Github page, including regenerating the outputs from the updated R code in my markdown document, how best is that done? I tried editing in-line using Github's web editor directly on the page, but I don't think that regenerates the embedded output images/graphs from R.
So the only other option that comes to mind, after googling, is just to follow the same steps outlined below and republish? But by doing so, will that produce a duplicate .md file on Github?
https://gist.github.com/JoshuaTPierce/b919168421b40e06481080eb53c3fb2f

Make your changes to the .Rmd and then knit your changes locally (i.e., on your computer).
Then you will only repeat the last part of the instructions:

In the Git window, check the box to stage Title.md [NOT .rmd] (and see note below)
Click "commit," add comment.
Click the green arrow to push to GitHub.
Go to GitHub, refresh the repository, and the markdown document with rendered code will be there

Note, make sure to also check the box for the folder containing the new/updated image files when checking the box to stage the .md document.
Doing this will push your local changes to the remote repository. There will be "duplicate files" in the sense of versioning of the files, but github will always show you the latest version of the files by default.
